# vs code: Launch multiple configurations at once

Tags: visual-studio-code, launch

I am playing around with cluster computing and would like to simulate a cluster with one leader node and multiple follower nodes. I can do that by setting up multiple configurations (one for each node). Now, I would like to run all of these configurations at once (or one after another).

Is it possible to do this?

[Someone else already tried to solve this question](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1616). The solution they came up with was to have a new `launch.json` in a new `.vscode` folder for each configuration. This seems to work, but is impractical since I would like to start e.g. 20 (or 100) nodes.

Comment: Did you look at the "compound" option?  It can list all your configurations in one place to run in parallel.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations

Comment: Thanks @Mark This seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Do you know if how to start each configuration in its own external Terminal, @Mark ?

Comment: unfortunately this idea does not really work. i seem to be able to start 2 nodes. One in an external terminal and one in the integrated terminal. But so far I was not able to start e.e. 10

Comment: I currently use it to start three configurations.  Two are node-based gulp tasks and one is the chrome debugger.  They all use the debugger console.  What do you get in the debugger toolbar dropdown?

Comment: I will try that again tonight. Thank you @Mark

Comment: No, it does not work. What I can do is start the configurations one after another. Than I am able to switch between consoles. I am not able to start them at once and switch between consoles. **Additional Info:** I am starting all jobs from a single java file and depending on what params I pass, a different node spawns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations

**Compound launch configurations**

An alternative way to start multiple debug sessions is by using a compound launch configuration. A compound launch configuration lists the names of two or more launch configurations that should be launched in parallel. Optionally a preLaunchTask can be specified that is run before the individual debug sessions are started. The boolean flag stopAll controls whether manually terminating one session will stop all of the compound sessions.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Server",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Client",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/client.js"
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Server/Client",
      "configurations": ["Server", "Client"],
      "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}",
      "stopAll": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Compound launch configurations are displayed in the launch configuration dropdown menu.